# Estimating meteorological visibility from air chemical and particulate composition

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, air-pollution, atmospheric-dust

I have found here an answer that provides formula that only takes into account vapors, pressure and temperature - [What is the formula used for atmospheric visibility?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/what-is-the-formula-used-for-atmospheric-visibility)

Is there an approach that also considers particulate matter and gases concentration? I am actually looking to account for as many contributing factors as possible, to achieve the best estimation, such as hydrometeors density,and whatever else may be related.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to take into account as many contributing factors as possible, you will need a complete [radiative transfer model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_radiative_transfer_codes), preferably a physics-based one (as opposed to fast radiative transfer models that are often incorporated into weather or climate models).

A radiative transfer model takes as input atmospheric composition in one or three dimensions, scattering databases for suspended matter such as aerosols or clouds (if the model includes scattering from particles), a molecular spectroscopic database such as HITRAN, as well as many configuration parameters.  Some models are only valid for certain areas of the atmospheric spectrum.  Some make line-by-line calculations (where "line" here means a location in the spectrum), others make broadband estimates directly.  Examples of well-known line-by-line models that cover visible wavelengths include [LBLRTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LBLRTM) and [LibRadtran](http://www.libradtran.org/doku.php). They may not be able to calculate visibility directly, but they should be able to calculate those quantities from which visibility can be estimated.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great insight.

Comment: Such models, however, are not feasible for my use-case, and I am not versed enough in the sciences to deduce a simpler solution for visibility from such complex models.
However now I understand that I phrased my question incorrectly.
What I actually looking for is an analytical formula, that gives a sufficiently good estimate for horizontal visibility, and that takes into account multiple parameters from a single sampling point (or homogeneous atmosphere)

Answer (score 1):

This is best answered with the Koschmeider Equation. The Koschmeider Equation which estimates visible range based on the particulate matter is as follows:

Koschmeider Equation (units in ft. or m) = (1200 km μg/m^3 )/(particle concentration (μg/m^3 ) )

Comment: A reference for this would improve the answer.